# Way of using sorted function in a different manner?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am creating a game of poker using python3 and for sorting the hands i am doing it like this :

`C < D < H < S`    and     `2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9 < T < J < Q < K < A`.

The output looks like this:

`Sorted Hand: ['D5', 'DA', 'DT', 'HA', 'SQ']`

But I need it to look like:

`Sorted Hand: ['D5', 'DT', 'DA', 'HA', 'SQ']`.

I am using the sorted function to do this, is there any way to customize the way the sorted function works and make it so it isn't taking the letters alphabetically but numerically? I'm at a loss here... =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k1, k2 = ['C','D','H','S'], ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A']
data = ['D5','DA','DT','HA','SQ']
print sorted(data, key=lambda x: k1.index(x[0]) * 13 + k2.index(x[1]))
```

**Output**

```
['D5', 'DT', 'DA', 'HA', 'SQ']
```

Comment: You'll probably want to say `* 13`, if i'm understanding this right, so that `CA` (sort value: 12) doesn't appear after `D2` (sort value: 10).

Comment: using a lambda function was my original guess but I kept forgetting the index part, otherwise my first guess was extremely similar >.< Thank you though! can't up vote yet but If I could you'd certainly get it

Answer (score 1):

Just a variant of what @thefourtheye already posted

```
def customSort(card):

    suit, value = card
    value_lookup = {'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14}

    return value_lookup.get(value, int(value))

print sorted(['D5', 'DA', 'DT', 'HA', 'SQ'], key=customSort)
```

Comment: The `.get` method of dictionaries exists to simply the logic in your return statement: `return value_lookup.get(value, int(value))`.  Might also return a tuple like `(suit, value_lookup.get(value, int(value))` so that suit order was consistent, but it's not clear from the OP whether that's desired or not.